# Xna Content Pipeline Extension - Loading other content within custom processor

Tags: c#, xna, content-pipeline

I'm currently experimenting with Xna Content Pipeline extensions. Within that experimentation, I'm trying to load a file that contains another 'content item' that is in need of loading. For example:

```
public class CustomItem
{
    public string Name;
    public Texture2D Texture;
}
```

Now, in my content processor, I can create a new instance of 'CustomItem' and initialize the Name field, since it's simply a string. However, I can't load the texture file during content compilation (NOTE: The texture is just an example, ideally I'd like to be able to load any other content type).

What I'm looking for is something like:

```
// ... start class ...

public override CustomItem Process(SomeInputFormat input, ContentProcessorContext context)
{
    return new CustomItem()
    {
        Name = input.ItemName,
        Texture = context.LoadAsset<Texture2D>(input.ItemTexturePath)   // I realise LoadAsset<T>() does not exist - it's an example of what would be ideal
    };
}

// ... end class ...
```

Does anyone know if this is actually possible, and if so, how to go about it? I'd rather not go down the route of late loading the other content items if possible, or creating my own, custom content loading using binary readers and writers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use `Texture2D` in the content pipeline. You have to use `Texture2DContent`, which is a proxy-type for the former. In turn, you must have a mechanism in your type for allowing the member to be `Texture2DContent` at content build time, but `Texture2D` at run-time. [This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2009/07/02/automatic-xnb-serialization-and-content-classes.aspx) gives you three ways of doing this.

You can use `ContentProcessorContext.BuildAndLoadAsset` to get your `Texture2DContent` object. This texture data will be embedded into your `.xnb` file for that asset.

If you don't actually need to use the texture data in the pipeline, and in particular if you intend to share the same texture between multiple assets, you can use `ContentProcessorContext.BuildAsset` to get an `ExternalReference` to the texture, which is built into its own `.xnb` file, external to your asset's `.xnb` file (and `ContentManager` will handle the loading for you).

Comment: Cheers for the swift reply. I had read somewhere about the Texture2DContent, but was hoping there was a nicer way of going about it. That article really explains it well, though, so I know fully understand it.